# Why will my computer not power on after making Ubuntu my OS and deleting Windows?

Tags: boot, live-usb

Wiped my Dell laptop’s disc and installed Ubuntu desktop as my OS using a live USB. Seemed to work well and used it successfully for a while but when I powered it off and came back about an hour later computer will not turn on and when I press or hold the power button it does absolutely nothing. Made sure it was plugged in properly and doubt it was any hardware issue as I just bought the computer new less than a week ago. Any ideas or steps for me to take? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have power at the plug, and that the battery is charged?  Power switch "does nothing" sounds like a hardware issue, but hard to  return under warranty without the original Windows installation.

Comment: Try resetting the power to the laptop.  Pull all the power (remove battery if removable).  Then press and hold down the power button for 15-30 seconds.  Plug back into power and try to power back on.